# Powershell and $HOME variable: broken if you move your default data folders to another drive?

Tags: powershell, user-profiles

While playing with powershell, I've just noticed that the `$HOME` variable won't give me the correct result if the user's data folders are moved to a different drive. For instance, let's assume two drives (C: and D:) and that the user has moved his Documents data folder to D:.

When that happens, `$HOME` still resolves to `C:\Users\username\...` and that means that using it for getting the user's [profile file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1) won't give me access to his profile file (which now is in `D:\users\username\Documents\Powershell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Any tips on how to get to the user's profile when the user moves his data folders to another drive?

Thanks.

Comment: Do `%USERPROFILE%` or `$USERPROFILE` work?

Comment: Doesn't the linked page already answer the question, right in the next section?

Comment: Yes it does...though....sorry guys :(

Comment: Documents, Pictures, Music, Movies... are separate folders in the home folder and can be moved around, but the home folder is always at the old location so obviously `$HOME` can't be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$PROFILE` variable that's described in the next section of the linked page.

```
PS> notepad $profile
```

(While it is a custom type with several properties, it can also be used on its own, as its .ToString() directly returns the current user's profile path.)

Answer (score 4):

You may find the Documents folder in PowerShell by the following:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
```

This will work better for the case where Documents was redirected.

Comment: to be more generic use `[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::MyDocuments)`